# Open source chat room for Ruby

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

Do you folks know of a rails chat room package that fulfills these criterion?

- customizable
- very simple with no bells and whistles

I am building a software with a chat component, and I was wondering if you folks had any idea there!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would look at:
     http://github.com/maccman/juggernaut 
     http://github.com/endtwist/AjaxIM

Here is an example of how to make a simple group chat with the new juggernaut: http://dailyjs.com/2010/09/13/juggernaut/

Comment: how well does these work with a ruby server?

Comment: should not be very difficult if you read the documentation for juggernaut the requirements are node.js, redis and ruby at least for the new version of juggernaut. ajaxim is based on node.js so if you can run node.js on your server you would be good to go.